# Dialogue écrit en langue coupée

Tags: dialogues

J'ai trouvé dans le manuscrit [*Guerre*](https://data.over-blog-kiwi.com/1/46/09/61/20220507/ob_89ef75_guerre-louis-ferdinand-celine.pdf), un dialogue écrit par Céline en langue coupée. Le narrateur demande des renseignements à un artilleur dont la langue a été, effectivement, coupée par un éclat d'obus :

> — T’en as vu fusiller déjà toi ? que je demande à l’artilleur, celui
> justement qu’avait un éclat dans le poumon et puis un autre éclat qui
> lui avait coupé juste le bout de la langue.
>
> **— Ben en ai vu ain au bodo à Sisonne ils iraient chi na dezu qui a
> faïï y mett en rois fois… Est pas rôle.**
>
> Ça allait pas mieux.
>
> **— Eureusement a ajudant, qu’il a ajouté, y a fouu rois bâl encore an
> la gueueule.**

Serait-il possible de reconstruire ces phrases en français standard ?

J'ai une vague idée :

— Bien, j'en ai vu un au bord à Sisonne, ils iraient **chi na dezu qui a faïï y
mett en rois fois(?)**... Ce n'est pas drôle.

— Heureusement **a ajudant (?)**, qu’il a ajouté, il a foutu trois balles encore dans la
gueule.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: Je pense (sans garantie !) : **au bodo** → au bord de l'eau  ; **chi** → chez  ;  **na dezu**  →  pourrait être un nom propre, ce qui serait justifié par la suite car il faut un antécédent au *qui* sujet ; **qui a faïï y mett en rois fois** → qui a failli lui mettre en trois fois ; **a ajudant** (il) y a l'adjudant ; **y a fouu rois bâl** (il) lui a foutu trois balles...  (Tu dis *en langue coupée* mais je ne crois pas qu'on puisse parler d'une langue – au sens de langage – coupée).

Comment: **na** pourraient être *la*, la langue coupée l'empêche de bien prononcer les L initiaux (voir l'eau, l'adjudant), et **dezu** le prénom ou  l'occupation de la personne en question.

Comment: _Ils iraient_ c'est _ils tiraient_, pas le verbe _aller_. _dezu_ c'est peut-être tout simplement _dessus_. _a adjudant_, juste le _a_ de _adjudant_ répété, comme un bégaiement.

Comment: Ceci dit, l'effet escompté est peut-être justement qu'on ne comprenne pas tout :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

— Bien j'en ai vu un au poteau<sup>1</sup> à Sisonne, ils tiraient si mal dessus *qu'il a failli lui mettre* (?) ou *qu'il a fallu s'y mettre* (?) en trois fois… C'est pas drôle.

— Heureusement l'adjudant, qu’il a ajouté, il lui a foutu trois balles encore dans la gueule.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Poteau d'exécution.</sub>

Comment: _ils tiraient_ au pluriel?

Comment: @Frank Ah oui. Je ne suis pas convaincu que ça puisse être *lui mettre en trois fois*, ce n'est pas très plausible.

Comment: *Il a fallu*, peut-être.